Let $a$ be an odd integer number. Show that there is no $x\in R$ such that $x^2*[x]+a=[x^3]+[x]^2*\{x\}$
The problem
Let $a$ be an odd integer number. Show that there is no $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $a= [x^3]-[x]^3-x*[x]*\{x\} \in Z => x*[x]*\{x\}\in Z $
My idea
By using the propriety $x=[x]+ \{x\}$ strategically so we can get rid of some parts of the equation I got that $a=\{x\} \cdot (3x^2+[x^2])-\{x\}^3\in \mathbb Z$ and should be odd, I'm not sure if this result is good
I don't know how to proceed forward. I hope one of you can help me!

Isn't $x=-\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}$ a counterexample? (You get $a=1$)

@ChrisLewis Sorryyy, it was a mistake in writing. Can you look at my edit?

Could you update the title and explain in your question how you got to the second formulation from the first?

Using $x=\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+\{x\}$ is the right idea, because you can use properties of $\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$ (it's an integer) and of $\{x\}$ (it's in $[0,1)$). The other property used below is that if $n$ is an integer and $\nu$ any real, $\lfloor n+\nu\rfloor=n+\lfloor \nu\rfloor$.
Substituting in,
\begin{align} a&= \left\lfloor x^3\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor^3-x\cdot \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \cdot \{x\}\\
&=\left\lfloor \left(\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+\{x\}\right)^3\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor^3-x\cdot \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \cdot \{x\} \\
&=\left\lfloor \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor^3+3\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor^2\{x\}+3\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \{x\}^2+\{x\}^3\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor^3-x\cdot \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \cdot \{x\}\\
&=\left\lfloor 3\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor\{x\}\left(\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor+\{x\}\right)+\{x\}^3\right\rfloor-x\cdot \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \cdot \{x\}\\
&=\left\lfloor 3x\cdot \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \cdot \{x\}+\{x\}^3\right\rfloor-x\cdot \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \cdot \{x\}
\end{align}
Now, if we want $a$ to be an integer, the term $x\cdot \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \cdot \{x\}$ must be an integer; call it $k$. But then
\begin{align}
a&=\left\lfloor 3k+\{x\}^3\right\rfloor-k\\
&=3k+\left\lfloor \{x\}^3\right\rfloor-k\\
&=2k
\end{align}
which is an even integer.
